# How to get the Cloudinary upload widget to work?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

All I am trying to do at this point is get the quick example working as shown here - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget

This is my code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>


    <button id="upload_widget" class="cloudinary-button">Upload files</button>


<script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  <script type="text/javascript">  
    var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
      cloudName: 'cloudname', 
      uploadPreset: 'uploadPreset'}, (error, result) => { 
        if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
          console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
        }
      }
    )

    document.getElementById("upload_widget").addEventListener("click", function(){
        myWidget.open();
      }, false);

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the "Upload files" button the grey box of the upload widget does appear but all I see inside is a loading icon.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working perfectly fine for me locally and on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brinkpress/pen/JjjKgQQ) without making a single change to the code. I even uploading two pictures using it, which you should check if they appeared in your Cloudinary account. Don't worry, they are clean.

Since I can't check if the images were uploaded to your account, I created a Cloudinary account of my own and verified that the widget is indeed working fine. I only checked it by changing to my cloudName and preset.

Here's the [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/brinkpress/pen/JjjKgQQ)

Your code below since Codepen Links need to have code accompany them.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>


    <button id="upload_widget" class="cloudinary-button">Upload files</button>


<script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  <script type="text/javascript">  
    var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
      cloudName: 'dw62s0tlm', 
      uploadPreset: 'rossm67'}, (error, result) => { 
        if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
          console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
        }
      }
    )

    document.getElementById("upload_widget").addEventListener("click", function(){
        myWidget.open();
      }, false);

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from their support (which worked) -

The most common reason why that would happen is if the HTML file that contains the code for the widget is opened in the browser directly, via the file:// protocol. In order for this to work, the file should be opened from within your localhost through a web server via HTTP.

For example, if your system has Python installed you can quickly run a simple HTTP server in the same directory as your file which would make it accessible.

For example in Python 3:

`python3 -m http.server`

Python 2.7:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Then navigating to http://localhost:8000/index.html would run the code and should allow you to launch the widget.